# Using GraphQL Codegen Typed Document Node Fragment to Create Query

Tags: graphql

I'm using GraphQL Code Generator to create typed DocumentNode fragments e.g.

```
export const MMovieConnectionFragmentDoc = {"kind":"Document","definitions":[{"kind":"FragmentDefinition","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"MMovieConnection"},"typeCondition":{"kind":"NamedType","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"MMovieConnection"}},"selectionSet":{"kind":"SelectionSet","selections":[{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"edges"},"selectionSet":{"kind":"SelectionSet","selections":[{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"node"},"selectionSet":{"kind":"SelectionSet","selections":[{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"id"}},{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"mMovieActors"},"selectionSet":{"kind":"SelectionSet","selections":[{"kind":"Field","name":{"kind":"Name","value":"id"}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]} as unknown as DocumentNode<MMovieConnectionFragment, unknown>;
```

I'm trying to use this fragment to create a simple GraphQL query e.g.

```
gql`query myQuery {
      myQuery {
          ...MMovieConnection
      }
  }
  ${MMovieConnectionFragmentDoc}
`
```

But this generates error: **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')**

If I create a fragment in this standard way, the query is created successfully:

```
fieldsFragment = gql`fragment MMovieConnection on MMovieConnection {
    edges {
        node {
            id
        }
    }
}`;
```

The standard fragment object is equivalent to the MMovieConnectionFragmentDoc object but has an additional loc property that includes a source property.

```
loc: {
    start: 0,
    end: 239,
    source: {
      body: "fragment MMovieConnection on MMovieConnection {\n            edges {\n                node {\n                    id\n                    mMovieActors {\n                        id\n                    }\n                }\n            }\n        }",
      name: "GraphQL request",
      locationOffset: {
        line: 1,
        column: 1,
      },
    },
  },
```

So gql seems to need the loc and source property when using fragments in queries.

But is there a way to use MMovieConnectionFragmentDoc to create a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the fragment back to a string and then wrapping in gql works.

```
import * as graphql from 'graphql';

fragment = gql`${graphql.print(MMovieConnectionFragmentDoc)}`;

gql`query myQuery {
        myQuery {
            ...myFragmentName
        }
    }
    ${fragment}
`;
```

Comment: Are you aware of any way to get the type of the query's variables from the `TypedDocumentNode`?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? Are you able to provide a more detailed example?